# Failed to build 'undrop-for-innodb'

Tags: mysql, gcc, makefile

I recently deleted my table and need to recover structure. I found this tool:

```
https://github.com/twindb/undrop-for-innodb
```

But after I use 'make' command on Linux Debian 9 building crash with this error:

```
https://pastebin.com/zr32zDzM
```

How to fix it? I really don't have any expirience with 'make' or gcc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check https://github.com/twindb/undrop-for-innodb/issues/3

You need to add -fgnu89-inline to CFLAGS